# In MTM, how can I reuse a test case in different environments?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Lets suppose we have a very simple test case: navigate to the homepage of a website. I want to reuse this test case among different test plans for different environments (DEV, QA, PROD). Therefore the location of the service will change depending on the test plan I am using.

How can I ensure that when the tester sees the "Action" instruction in MTM it shows the correct URL for the current environment?

Can I do this based on test plans? Is there a different approach?

Comment: Can you please explain the `location of the service`? Which service? Also the URL is a link you added in your test plan?

Comment: @Schaliasos by "location of the service" I mean the URI of the service (e.g. Dev may use http://dev.myservice while QA may user http://QA.myservice etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention that your test is automated so I will give you an answer for manual testing.

1. In your test case DON'T use specific URL value. Just say "*Navigate to the home page of the site.*"
2. Crate only one `Test Plan`.
3. In the Test Plan create 3 different `Test Configurations`, one per environment.
4. In the Test Plan's Properties window add 3 links for each environment. For example, for Qa add new link with `Description = Qa` & `Link = http://qa.myservice/`
5. When you add this Test Case in a Test Suite, right click on the Test Case and select `Select test configurations for selected tests` and select the configurations (environments) that the test case will run.

When your testers will run the test cases will select the correct link depending on the configuration.

Comment: According to this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286583(v=VS.100).aspx#AddLinks) the links section is used to "add external links to a Web site that has more information about the application that you are testing. Or you might want to link to a document about the requirements that you need to test for the current sprint from your test plan. This allows you to associate any relevant information with your test plan so it can easily be located by a tester." You suggest that we use this feature to inform the testers about the URL they should use depending on the environment.